# Create a Windows readable/writable FAT32 partition

Tags: raspbian, windows, filesystem

I have Raspbian installed on my Pi. I want to create a FAT32 partition on the unallocated space on my SD card. I followed [this guide](http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/adding-a-fat32-partition-to-raspbian-on-a-rasperry-pi/) to create a partition. The partition is readable/writable on Raspbian and Mac OS without any problems. However, the partition does not show up in Windows Explorer. I opened Disk Management on Windows and found that this is no drive letter assigned to that partition. And Disk Management does not allow me to assign a drive letter to it.

Comment: Why not just create the partition from inside Windows? (instead of on the Pi itself)

Comment: @tapped-out: Disk Management does not allow me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't know to look past the first partition on an SD card, so won't find the one you made.

Comment: Yes it does, but it sees it as 'unknown partition rather than the fat32 partition that I created using gparted

Comment: Alright then: “Windows cannot read data past the first partition on an SD card.” Happy now? The only difference is semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ext2+ driver for windows. good luck

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/